# How to join two dataframes with dplyr based on two columns with different names in each dataframe?

Tags: r, dataframe, merge, dplyr

This is a really simple question, but can't find a suitable answer here.

How does one join two data.frames with `dplyr` based on **two columns** with different names in each data.frame?

With `base::merge` one can simply `merge`:

```
df3 <- merge(df1, df2, by.x=c("name1", "name2"), by.y=c("name3", "name4"))
```

where `df1$name1 == df2$name3` and `df1$name2 == df2$name4`.

How does one do this in `dplyr`?

---

I know that one can use the `by` function in `dplyr` to do join two data.frames with based on one column with a different name:

```
df3 <- dplyr::left_join(df1, df2, by=c("name1" = "name3"))
```

Comment: `by = c("name1" = "name3", "name2" = "name4")` should work?

Comment: http://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/two-table.html

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
df3 <- dplyr::left_join(df1, df2, by=c("name1" = "name3", "name2" = "name4"))
```

Comment: Does this work also with autobox?